# How to Select all Checkboxes with jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, gridview

I need to "check" all of the checkboxes in an asp.net gridview. I can do so with code-behind but would rather do this on the client side with jquery. The column that the checkbox is stored in is called "displayButton" because it displays another action button once a checkbox is checked.

Not sure how to begin here.

Comment: your rendered html would help.. (if it's readable... (asp.net))

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
$('#girdid input [type="checkbox"]').attr('checked', true);
```

this is solution. I hope it helps

Comment: In jQuery version 1.5.x and earlier `.attr()` is the proper method however in version 1.6 the `.prop()` function was added to set/get property values for elements. Docs: http://api.jquery.com/prop/

Answer (score 2):

You would start with a selector that selects all the checkboxes that you want to check, then use the `prop()` function to change their 'checked' properties to true:

```
$('input:checkbox').not(':checked').prop('checked', true);
```

Note: Check mblase75's response for jQuery version issues.

**--UPDATE--**

I ran a jsperf and not checking if the checkbox is already checked is quite a lot slower (approximately 50% slower) than just using the `.prop()` function to set all checkboxe's checked property to true.

Comment: Why bother with `.not(':checked')` at all?

Answer (score 1):

`$("input:checkbox").prop("checked",true)`

or `$("input:checkbox").attr("checked","checked")` for jQuery 1.5.x or earlier.

That said: you say you would rather not do this in ASP.Net, but if it's at all possible your users will have JavaScript turned off, you'll have to do it server-side.

Answer (score 1):

for jquery lower than 1.6

```
$('input:checkbox').attr('checked', "checked");
```

and for 1.6+

```
$('input:checkbox').prop('checked', true);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#id input:checkbox").prop("checked", true);
```

or

```
$(".class input:checkbox").prop("checked", true);
```